# formula that contains a range that keeps the range intact

Tags: microsoft-excel

Is there a way to copy a formula that contains a range that keeps the range intact? For example:

```
=SUM(A1:A7)
```

Then I want to copy that to the next row down and have it be:

```
=SUM(A8:A14)
```

When I copy the formula and paste, all it does is increment by one, so I end up with:

```
=SUM(A2:A8)
```

I am trying to summarize weekly data in a different section of the spreadsheet.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a **non-volatile** formula, try using the `INDEX` function and mathematically generating the row values:

```
=SUM(INDEX($A:$A,(ROW()-1)*7+1):INDEX($A:$A,ROW()*7))
```

This can be adapted to any starting row, but, as written, assumes starting in Row 1

To adapt to a different starting row, note that the row formulas can be rewritten as:

```
Start Row:  =(ROW()-start_row_number)*7+1
End  Row:   =(ROW()-start_row_number+1)*7
```

where `start_row_number` is a hard-coded integer.

**EDIT:**  As noted by @Jeeped in comments, the formula can be modified to:

```
=SUM(INDEX($A:$A,(ROW(1:1)-1)*7+1):INDEX($A:$A,ROW(1:1)*7))
```

which can start at **any** row.

Comment: `=SUM(INDEX($A:$A,(ROW(1:1)-1)*7+1):INDEX($A:$A,ROW(1:1)*7))` can start from anywhere as well.

Comment: @Jeeped Excellent! Thanks.

Comment: that work very well .thanx.but now i need another formula.you see i apply that one you just give me on two column i need the first one out come in a cell & the other column out come in the next .c1 =SUM(INDEX($A:$A,(ROW(1:1)-1)*7+1):INDEX($A:$A,ROW(1:1)*7))... c2 =SUM(INDEX($b:$b,(ROW(1:1)-1)*7+1):INDEX($b:$b,ROW(1:1)*7))...& rebate for c3&c4..

Comment: @user1129447 This seems like a different question.  If my answer solves your problem above, kindly mark it as Accepted.  See [What should I do when someone answers my question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers). Then post a new question with your new problem, and include samples of data and how you have tried to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `SUM`, `OFFSET` & `ROW` for this.

And using 7 as a divisional factor, as you are summing every 7 rows.

```
=SUM(OFFSET($A$1,(ROW()*7)-6-1,0,7))
```

Enter this in to B1 and drag down.

Note. This will only work from ROW 1 to match the example given in the question.